# How to dynamically generate with based on screen sizes in SASS Function

Tags: sass

My target is to create dynamic width based on screen sizes in %

How can I use `screen.width` property of JavaScript in SASS?

```
@function screen-width ($expected, $container) {
  @return ($expected/$container) *100% ;
}
.demo {
  width: screen-width(650px, 1000px);
}
```

I want the `screen-width` to take container width and expected width should be dynamically changed based on screen resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access objects or variables from JavaScript in CSS. SASS is just a preprocessor which compiles to CSS at the build time. Thus using `screen.width` which is available on `window` object can not be accessed in your SASS code.

You can try following alternate approaches for whatever you're trying to acieve:

1) Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

2) If this does solve your problem, On `window.onload` event, read the `screen.width` property and set the width programmatically using javascript.

3) If you need it the width to be set again if the window is resized, then use `onresize` event listener.

Comment: @Bhutanwangchuk Since you're new on this site, on stackoverflow you avoid commenting thank you or other stuff unless it is something technical. Also, if you find any answer useful then you can accept it or upvote.